# Возврат результата системного вызова

Tags: c, ассемблер

Имею такую функцию:

```
void syscall3(int num, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    asm("int\t$0x80\n\t"
        : /* Сюда надо впихнуть возврат значения */
        : "a"(num), "b"(arg1), "c"(arg2), "d"(arg3)
    );
}
```

Как сделать чтоб функция возвращала результат системного вызова в long int?

Comment: [пример вызова POSIX `write(fd, data, byte_count)`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/625406/23044) syscall для AMD64 архитектуры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как понимаю, вы теперь не под ARM пишете, а под x86? Вот:

```
int
syscall3(int num, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    int ret;

    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "int $0x80;"
        : "=a"(ret)
        : "a"(num), "b"(arg1), "c"(arg2), "d"(arg3)
    );

    return ret;
}
```

Возвращает `int`, а не `long int`, так как, судя по всему, система у вас 32-разрядная.

Comment: И под arm и под x86.;) хм делал абсолютно также и получал ошибку сегментации, развечто у меня было без volatile__