# Вывести символ через ассемблерную вставку

Tags: linux, c, ассемблер, gcc

Под linux x86_64 не получается вывести символ через ассемблерную вставку. Делаю так:

```
void putc(char symbol) {
    __asm__ (
        "mov $4, %%eax\n\t"
        "mov $1, %%ebx\n\t"
        "mov %0, %%ecx\n\t"
        "mov $1, %%edx\n\t"
        "int $0x80\n\t"
        : /* no output registers */
        : "c" ((unsigned int)symbol)
    );
}
```

GCC генерирует следующий ассемблер:

```
mov $4, %eax
mov $1, %ebx
mov %ecx, %ecx
mov $1, %edx
int $0x80
```

Видимо проблема в регистре `%ecx`, что в него не вставляется адрес символа `symbol`.

Компилирую gcc:

```
$ gcc -ffreestanding -Wall -pedantic -ansi -std=c89 main.c -o main
$ ./main
```

Почему не выводит символ на `stdout`?

Comment: В 64-ёх битном Linux немного другой номер у вызова **write**. Номера всех системных вызовов можно выяснить в файле `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h`. (См. также статью на хабре, ссылку на которую я привёл в своём ответе).

Comment: Кстати, для отладки, наверняка, будет полезна утилита strace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Видимо проблема в регистре `%ecx`, что в него не вставляется адрес символа `symbol`.

Совершенно верно. Но вы можете передать в ассемблерную вставку адрес `symbol`, просто поставив оператор взятия адреса (**&**) перед именем переменной.

Убедитесь, что компилируете для x86, и тогда заработает. (За это отвечает флаг компилятора `-m32`; вероятно, придётся допоставить 32-ух битные библиотеки).

Вот, на мой взгляд, несколько улучшенный вариант:

```c
int putc(char symbol) {
    int result;
    __asm__ (
        "int $0x80"
        : "=a" (result)  /* возвращаемое значение */
        : "a" ((unsigned int) 4)  /* номер системного вызова */
        , "b" ((unsigned int) 1)  /* номер файла для вывода */
        , "c" ((unsigned int) &symbol)  /* адрес буфера */
        , "d" ((unsigned int) 1)  /* сколько байт вывести */
        : "memory"  /* будет читаться основная память */
    );
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return putc(argv[argc > 1][0]);
}
```

**Использованные материалы:**

- [Находим код системного вызова mkdir](https://habrahabr.ru/post/155645/) (Habrahabr)
- [Ассемблерные вставки в GCC](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/articles/gcc_inline_asm?page=3) (GameDev)

**Дополнительно и более подробно:**

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html

---

*P.S.: спасибо за интересный вопрос*

Comment: Да, один важный момент -- следование ABI, из-за ломания которого могут возникать интересные эффекты.

Comment: В документации GCC (ссылка в сообщении) сказано, что memory clobber надо указывать, даже когда идёт лишь только чтение из памяти. В противном случае это может привести к непонятным результатам при включенной оптимизации.

Comment: @mymedia могу подтвердить, что без указания "memory" в clobbers части, мой пример ломается, если с оптимизацией компилировать.

Comment: @mymedia хороший же комментарий был про git log )

Answer (score 4):

Вариант для AMD64 архитектуры:

```c
int putchar_inline_assembly(char c)
{
  int ret;
  __asm__ volatile (
    /* AssemblerTemplate */
    "syscall\n\t"
    /* : OutputOperands */
    : "=a"( ret )
    /*  [ : InputOperands */
    : "D"( 1 ),  /* write to stdout */
      "S"( &c ), /* buffer address */
      "d"( 1 ),  /* write 1 character from the buffer */
      "a"( 1 )   /* use the write syscall */
    /*  [ : Clobbers ] ] */
    : "rcx", "r11", "memory"
    );
  return ret;
}
```

[gcc может это превратить в](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(colouriseAsm:'0',compileOnChange:'0'),source:'int+putchar_inline_assembly(char+c)%0A%7B%0A++int+ret%3B%0A++__asm__+volatile+(%0A++++/*+AssemblerTemplate+*/%0A++++%22syscall%5Cn%5Ct%22%0A++++/*+:+OutputOperands+*/%0A++++:+%22%3Da%22(+ret+)%0A++++/*++%5B+:+InputOperands+*/%0A++++:+%22D%22(+1+),++/*+write+to+stdout+*/%0A++++++%22S%22(+%26c+),+/*+buffer+address+*/%0A++++++%22d%22(+1+),++/*+write+1+character+from+the+buffer+*/%0A++++++%22a%22(+1+)+++/*+use+the+write+syscall+*/%0A++++/*++%5B+:+Clobbers+%5D+%5D+*/%0A++++:+%22memory%22%0A++++)%3B%0A++return+ret%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.65438786565547,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:'0',directives:'0'),options:'-O2'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+6.3',t:'0')),k:47.34561213434453,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
putchar_inline_assembly(char):
        movb    %dil, -4(%rsp)
        movl    $1, %edi
        leaq    -4(%rsp), %rsi
        movl    %edi, %edx
        movl    %edi, %eax
        syscall
        ret
```

Что похоже на [ассемблер, который можно руками написать для `write(1)` системного вызова](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux):

```
# ssize_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte);
movq $1, %rdi   # write to stdout
movq $buf, %rsi # buffer address
movq $1, %rdx   # write 1 character from the buffer
movq $1, %rax   # use the write syscall
syscall         # make syscall
```

- [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989/4279)
- [How to invoke a system call via sysenter in inline assembly (x86/amd64 linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9506353/4279)

Аргументы для системного вызова передаются через регистры без
стека. Порядок аргументов (AMD64 ABI A.2.1.1):

1. %rdi ("D")
2. %rsi ("S")
3. %rdx ("d")
4. %rcx (%r10 — интерфейс ядра)
5. %r8
6. %r9

Номер системного вызова `write()` в Linux x86-64 равен `1` (`grep write /usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h`) и передается
в syscall через %rax ("a") регистр. После syscall %rcx и %r11 регистры могут быть затёрты
(A.2.1.2).

Ассемблерная вставка выполняет аналог C кода:

```c
ret = write(/*STDOUT_FILENO*/1, &c, /*sizeof char*/1);
```